# How to test a dropbox upload in Java with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dropbox

I have the following code snippet:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dropbox")
public class DropboxController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DropboxController.class);

    @Autowired
    DropboxService dropboxService;

    @Autowired
    DbxClientV2 dropboxClient;

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String handleFileUplad(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("filePath") String filePath) throws Exception {
        dropboxService.uploadFile(file, filePath);
        return "You successfully uploaded " + filePath + "!!";
    }
```

Now I want to test whether the upload works. How can I do this? How would be the syntax when I try it with curl?

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/curl-post-request-examples/

To POST with a file, add this -F file=@"path/to/data.txt"

```
$ curl -F file=@"path/to/data.txt" http://localhost:8080/dropbox/upload
```

Answer (score 0):

Also as an alternative you can use Postman
Add form-data as body with 2 parameters and select the type as file

[image]